# How to implement Image Scroll view in android?

Tags: android, image, scroll, android-imageview, pinchzoom

I have a set of around 300 images. I want to implement scroll view of images. when I scroll, then next image should be displayed.

When I went through different forums and documentation I found that there are many ways to do this. HorizontalScrollView, Gallery, ViewAnimator,ViewSwitcher etc

Please tell me what is best and efficient way to implement. I should also have the ability to zoom each individual image.

Comment: ViewSwitcher isn't the way to go. Use HorizontalScrollView for the pictures... zooming however I think you'll need to code yourself.

Comment: Is there any sample code to use horizontal scroll with single image zooming?

Comment: yea, look here http://android-coding.blogspot.com/2011/01/scrollview-and-horizontalscrollview.html and here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/HorizontalScrollView.html but zooming... i have no idea about zooming really.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Gallery widget is deprecated since Jelly Bean.

you can use `ViewPager` or `HorizontalScrollView` for your purpose.

From the [Gallery](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Gallery.html) doc:

> This class is deprecated. This widget is no longer supported. Other
>   horizontally scrolling widgets include HorizontalScrollView and
>   ViewPager from the support library.